# How to iterate through list, per test in SilkTest?

Tags: list, automated-tests, silktest

I wrote Lists (Name, Item, etc.) for my Green Mountain Outpost Applikation.
I want the applikation to run automaticaly the testcase with 1 Persone and Item at the time. So that the app. runs 1 Person from list throug, than the second test with another.

[Testcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if7a3.jpg)

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtrfS.jpg)

[List for Name, Item, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIl0X.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
[ ] int x = 1
[-] for each Name in customers
    [ ] print(Name)
    [ ] // Name = customers[x]
    [ ] Artikel = items[x]
    [ ] CardN = cardnumber[x]
    [ ] Expi = expirationdate[x]
    [ ] print(Artikel)
    [ ] print(CardN)
    [ ] print(Expi)
    [ ] print("----------------------")
    [ ] Bestellung (Name, Artikel, CardN, Expi)
    [ ] 
    [ ] x++
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the data in Excel and make the test case as data driven.

Each row will be having one data combination.